# Template engine disables PHP

Tags: php, template-engine

So I build this template engine, but when I parse my files, it disables the php, which make me unable to get my sitename and stuff. This is the parser (rlly lightweight)

```
class Template {

    public  function __construct($directory) {
        $this->directory = $directory;
    }
public function getTemplate($filename) {
    $file = "app/themes/" . $this->directory . "/" . $filename . ".php";
    if(!file_exists($file)) {
        die("Het opgevraagde bestand bestaat niet.");
    } else {
        $this->content = file_get_contents($file);
        echo $this->content;
    }
}
```

}

Does anyone know a way to enable PHP again? By the way, I'm running this on my template:

`$core->getSitename`

Please note that this isn't any existing template engine.

Comment: So you're just loading a file into a variable using `file_get_contents()` and expecting that file to be executed as PHP rather than simply loaded.... that's not what `file_get_contents()` is for, `file_get_contents()` simply loads a file content into a string; it's what `include` or `require` are for

Comment: Methods shouldn't echo, they should _return_ values. Classes don't call `die`. Ever. If they can't do their job, they `throw new Exception`'s. `file_get_contents` does what it says on the tin: it gets the contents of a file, and returns it. PHP doesn't parse, compile let alone execute what is in that file, that's what `include` is for. Also: hard-coding a path in a class is a bad idea: what if the class is moved to another directory? Where is your code going to look for that template file? Last thing: you haven't written a parser. Yo have at best: a very limited file locator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply `include` the page (instead of loading it via `file()` etc.). If you do so, an output buffer comes in handy as well:

```
public function getTemplate($filename) {
    $file = "app/themes/" . $this->directory . "/" . $filename . ".php";
    if(!file_exists($file)) {
        die("Het opgevraagde bestand bestaat niet.");
        //better to throw an error instead
    } else {
        ob_start();
        include $file;
        $this->content = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
    }
}
```

---

There are alot of (good) template engines available for PHP. Instead of reinventing them, I'd suggest using one of them. However, if you still want to develop your own, look into their sources and find out how they solved problems you now face. A lot of thought and sweat went into their solutions.